# Currency Pipe formatting

Tags: angular, currency-formatting, angular2-pipe

I am using angular2 currency pipe for 'INR' and willing to get the output format in

`12,89,253 instead of 1,289,253` || `12,89,43,56,453 instead of 12,894,356,453`

i.e. format the amounts as per indian currency formatting instead of international formatting system. I couldn't find any possibility for this in the doc. Help!

Answer (score 0):

As per the angular documentation the currency and date pipes should have the following scripts reference as below

```
<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=Intl.~locale.en"></script>
```

[image]

Comment: I am not looking for browser support issues. This is a locale issue which is not resolved by polyfills

Comment: so what is that you are looking for?

Comment: the formatting is working, but its doing the formatting as per international currency system. I want the same by indian currency system. Same has been written in the question with examples

Comment: have you wrote a sample pipe for this? if so update them to the post. It is possible using the regular expression.

Comment: I am using the angular2 currency pipe, are you suggesting me to create a custom pipe?

Comment: yes. Currency by default separates to three digits.

Comment: that I can always do, but i am looking for a solution if it has been already implemented. My query on the existing feature

Comment: Not available in the existing package of angular